# CDO tranche spread

Tags: spread, cdo

An increase in default correlation ceteris paribus increases the value of the equity tranche of a CDO. This I get.

How then, do I make sense of the statement that as default correlation in the underlying credits increases, the spread ***decreases***?

Isn't the value of the tranche the spread it earns over LIBOR when there is enough funds to pass to the equity tranche?

Comment: Are you talking about a CDO or a synthetic CDO ?

Answer (score 2):

The intuition behind the statement "if correlation increases, the spread of a CDO junior tranche decreases" is as follows:

- If correlation increases, more probability mass of the default distribution is moving to the tails.
- The risk of joint default increases, but at the same time the chance of joint survivals increases.
- So the higher correlation, the higher the likelihood that there are no defaults.
- The junior tranche becomes less risky and the spread decreases.

Answer (score 1):

for synthetic cdo you could have a look at this paper -  http://home.gwu.edu/~sagca/JAI.pdf.

as for equity tranche, i understand that it receives residual cashflow i.e. remainings after paying all senior tranches.